# mimic same shape or apply to object: Rubik cube

Tags: modeling

I am trying to place this honeycomb patterns onto my object to match the real piece below. I have tried to shrink wrap and any option for it just doesn't work out. I imagined I could just make the honeycomb bend around the object then ill try the boolean option. If anyone has any other ideas please visually show me or link me to a video that could help.

[image]
[image: This is with the shrink wrap applied]
[image]
[image]

Comment: is it for 3D print or just image? If it's for an image you'd better use a Bump or Normal map

Comment: Just for imaging. I think that was what i did with my first speed cube model but when it formed around curves and beveled edges the honeycomb stretched around the bend.

Comment: so maybe prepare a honew comb mesh, bake its normals and use the normal map on your object? It should not be too difficult to make it fit with the faces

Comment: @adlowe07 Isn't that just issue of modifier order? Create flat honeycomb, Shrink, Solidify, Boolean ... or you can Knife project honeycomb and extrude ...

Comment: @moonboots, I'm not sure what you mean, so I searched "blender back normals" and found this video. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: What video? I meant BAKE normals, yes you'll easily find some tutorials on this topic

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I pasted the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LuEqvO9QsE

Comment: To be practical ... @moonboots's suggestion to use just material for such thing is easier to care of :) I would use probably bump (black&white) texture and Adaptive Subdive (Microdisplacement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Knife Project

Enable addon Extra Objects, add object Honeycomb.
Select Honeycomb, than Cube ...

[image]

... go to Front view <kbd>1</kbd> (direction of projection), switch to Edit mode, Select all vertices and search for **Knife Project** ...

[image]

... Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> in <kbd>Y</kbd> axis.

[image]

You would have to clean honeycomb ends - delete cube side face, delete honeycomb ends, Loop Select <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> and Fill face <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

In my case I didnt care to much about honeycomb position - I got close vertices on one beveled segment, so I used *Merge by Distance* 0.02 to make it nicer.

[image]

Anyway if you would need Subdivision modifier you would have to create nicer topology on sides to get away of n-gons.

Like now I used lowers bevel and enabled Normals > Auto Smooth.

Comment: Isn't that an Alt-S extrusion? I can't figure out what Y that would be.

Comment: For some reason I can't get mine to look like yours by the second image, so I kept going and nothing changed. The honeycomb is still not projected on the cube. I don't know if its because my honeycomb isn't a plane.

Comment: It seemed to be my honeycomb that wasn't working. I appended your honeycomb object into mine, and it immediately worked the way you demonstrated. Thanks

Comment: @RobinBetts ... some kind of joke I didn't understand? +1 for Alt-S. I extrude and move on Y axis since reference has vanishing pattern ends on sides.

Comment: Ahhhh!.. your ways are more subtle and closely observed than I thought :)  Glasshoppa will return to his cage.

Answer (score 2):

### Texture

as suggested by @moonboots ... one of the material option is Bump map ... just do a screenshot of your honeycomb object ...

[image]

... and use it as a texture for Displacement node.

[image]

You can use it just for bump effect or as for **Adaptive Displacement**. I'm not going to explain step by step, it was described dozen times.

[image]

---

*I just run into issue when used Subdivision modifier. I had to use Simple algorithm, because Catmull-Clark shifted UVmap. But Simple doesn't smooth lowpoly bevel of course. I have to study what is going on here.*